# setting title for one li tag based on the value of another li

Tags: jquery, title

My application is in mvc 3.
I am displaying 2 values in view from the model. Both are displaying in `li` tags as follows

```
foreach (Contact Contact in ModelList)
{
    <ul class="listAnB">
        <li id="liA">@Model.ValueA</li>
        <li id="liB">@Model.ValueB</li>
    </ul>
}
```

it is in the loop.

Its displaying correctly from model. But I need to set the `title` (tooltip) of first `li` on mouseover based on the value in the second li  using jquery.
That is if the second li `(liB).text="sometext"` then i need to set `(liA).attr('title')="some tool tip text"`

Can anybody please help me

Comment: I'm unclear about why "sometext" would get "some tool tip text" applied. Is there supposed to be a relationship between the values?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you meant.. :)

```
$('.listAnB li').mouseover(function() {
   if($(this).text()== "sometext"){
       $(this).siblings().text("some tool tip text");
   }
});
```

Comment: Is there any console errors being shown..???could u create a fiddle coz that would be much easier..

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
foreach (Contact Contact in ModelList)
{
    <ul class="listAnB">
        <li id="liA" title=""+@Model.ValueB>@Model.ValueA</li>
        <li id="liB">@Model.ValueB</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: NO i cant directly set valueb as tooltip of liA. I need to check if the vaue is some text then set tool tip with some other text

Comment: ok that too u can check inside the foreach why you are going for jquery